# how can I use PostgreSQL's "text" column type in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

Can I have in Django's model a column of PostgreSQL's "text" type? If so, how can I do that?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the [`TextField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.TextField)

> A large text field. The default form widget for this field is a Textarea.

Usage:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text_field = models.TextField("My field label", null=True, blank=True)
```

If the text is not too long, You could also consider [`CharField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.CharField)

> A string field, for small- to large-sized strings.
> For large amounts of text, use TextField.

> The default form widget for this field is a TextInput.

Usage:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    text_field = models.CharField("My field label", max_length=1024, null=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 1):

A customized CharField will give "text" DB type benefits while remaining compatible with other site code.

```
class CharField(models.CharField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs.setdefault('max_length', 65000)
        super(CharField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def db_type(self, connection):
        return 'text'

    def south_field_triple(self):
        """Only necessary if using South migrations, which you should."""
        from south.modelsinspector import introspector
        field_class = self.__class__.__module__ + "." + self.__class__.__name__
        args, kwargs = introspector(self)
        return (field_class, args, kwargs)
```

Using this field instead of models.CharField() allows you to skip that pesky max_length and varchar updates.

```
class Sausage(models.Model):
    length = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    title = CharField()
    recipe = models.TextField()
```

Which gives following SQL:

```
CREATE TABLE "w00t_sausage" (
    "id" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    "length" integer unsigned NOT NULL,
    "title" text NOT NULL,
    "recipe" text NOT NULL
)
```

They are both 'text' in a database, but represented as usual in admin and form widgets.